# Prioritize bluetooth tether over Wifi on an iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, tethering

I have an iPad tethered to my iPhone's internet using Bluetooth.  The iPad is also connected to a WiFi network which does not have internet access.  The iPad won't connect to the internet until I turn WiFi off, so I presume it's prioritizing the WiFi.  How can I reverse this priority?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you tether your iPad to your iPhone via WiFi? Bluetooth is atrociously slow and power consuming.

Comment: Because my iPad is running another app which requires a fast LAN connection all the time, I use a fast router instead of relying on the phone to always be nearby.  Also Bluetooth tethering uses less power than Wifi.

Comment: Ah. I meant bluetooth consumes more power for it's speed than WiFi does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem might be related to the DHCP server on the WiFi network, telling your iPad to use a 'default router' on its network.

If the DHCP server sends a value for the 'default router', then the iPad (or any computer, for that matter) will use that router address for all traffic that is not within any of the subnets to which it is attached. This is expected behaviour.

If you have access to the DHCP server's settings, try telling it not to give clients a 'default router', and the problem should go away.

Another suggestion is to turn off DHCP in the WiFi settings on the iPad, and allocate yourself a static address. Again, it helps if you are involved with network administration here, as otherwise you might allocate yourself an address that is already in use, and badness will ensue. But you could allocate yourself an address, a subnet mask and DNS server(s) - and do NOT set a 'router' address.

Comment: I need DHCP for other clients, so turning it off is not an option. I've never heard of a default router setting. Can it be turned off on a cheap Linksys router?

Comment: I meant on the iPad. You can tell it how to get an IP address in the WiFi settings. If you set the address manually ('static'), then you can set the 'router' setting to be empty for the WiFi interface.

Comment: Static IP address on the iPad works!  Thank you.  This also works on an iPhone to prioritize 4G over WiFi.